# Statistical distance of sum of random variable and arbitrary uniform variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The appendix of the following [paper](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2006/40040529/40040529.pdf#page=17) proves that the statistical difference between a uniform random variable and a sum of that uniform random variable with another (arbitrary) random variable has a certain upper bound.

More formally:

[image]

The proof is as follows:

[image]
[image]

Clarifications on several aspects of the proof would be greatly appreciated as I'm struggling to understand them:

1. "Hence that $0\leq Pr[X+U=w]\leq 1/K$" - I guess this is simply due to $Pr[U=w-a]=1/K$ since $U$ is a uniform random variable, and thus $ \sum_{a=0}^{M-1}{Pr[X=a] Pr[U=w-a]}=\frac{1}{K}\sum_{a=0}^{M-1}{Pr[X=a]}\leq \frac{1}{K} $ , where the last equation is simply because $Pr[X=a]$ is a probability function?
2. "and, if $M-1\leq w \leq K$, that $Pr[X+U=w] = 1/K$ - why is that? Because once $X$ has been selected, there is only a single $U$ that fits to be the right $w$ ? This seems odd to me, because if we take $w \in [0, M-1)$ then there is more than a single way to obtain it - we can have $X=w, U=0$ or $X=0, U=w$ and other combinations, in contrast to this case where $w \geq M-1$ so shouldn't the probability in (1) be more than $1/K$ ?
3. I understand the range separation below, however I'm lost in understanding the reasoning to each one of (a), (b), and (c):

[image]

Can anyone clarify how they turned $Pr[X+U=w]$ and $Pr[U=w]$ into the corresponding $1/K$ or $0$ in each of (a), (b) and (c) ?

For (b) I guess it's simply that $Pr[U=w]=1/K$, and once we choose $X$, $U=w-X$ also has chance of $1/K$ due to the range $M-1, K-1$ ? Is that right?

For (c) could it be that the range $K, M+K-2$ is unreachable for $U$ without adding $X$, hence the probability is 0 for just $U$ and uniform for $U+X$ ?

Sadly I can't figure out any reasoning for (a) other than they took an "upper bound" with $X=M-1$ hence $U+X \notin \{ 0, ..., M-2 \}$ however it is said they took $X=M-1$ after these equations.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at the proof, it seems to me that the lemma should add the assumption that $X$ and $U$ are independent.  (i) Yes we have $\sum_{a=0}^{M-1} P[X=a]P[U=w-a] \leq  \sum_{a=0}^{M-1} P[X=a](1/K)=(1/K)$.

Comment: (ii)  We have $$P[U=w-a]= \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1/K & \mbox{ if $w-a \in \{0, ..., K-1\}$} \\ 0 & \mbox{ else} \end{array}\right. $$ and if $w-a \in \{0, ..., K-1\}$ for all $a \in \{0, ..., M-1\}$ then we have $\sum_{a=0}^{M-1} P[X=a]\underbrace{P[U=w-a]}_{1/K}$.

Comment: I understand what you say about (ii) but I don't understand what is so special about the range of $M-1 \leq w < K$, couldn't they apply similar argument for (i) ? Furthermore, I still don't see why $Pr[U+x=w]$ actually sums up exactly to $1/K$ when $w$ is in that special range of $M-1, K$?

Comment: Yes the same applies for (i). Indeed $P[U=s]$ is either 0 or $1/K$ for all integers $s$, which means $P[U=s]\leq 1/K$ for all integers $s$. For (i) we just use that upperbound , with no worries about figuring out which terms are actually 0 and which are $1/K$. For (ii) there is a extra condition that ensures no terms are zero, they are all $1/K$, as I indicated with an underbrace in my previous comment.

Comment: All right, thanks. What about (iii)?